# Did I incorrectly solve for the distance of a traveling plane along a runway? (first time on math overflow)

Tags: linear-algebra

**A plane is travelling at an initial velocity (iv) of 5 meters/second, accelerating (acc) down a runway at 3.15 meters/seconds2 for 33.2 seconds (t), and then it takes off the ground. Determine the distance traveled before takeoff.**

This is a homework problem I was given. I came up with 101.43 meters. Here's how I thought through the problem:
In the first second= 5 Meters traveled
Seconds 2-33= 3.15*32 meters traveled Meters traveled after 33 seconds= 100.8 20% of 3.15= 0.63 Meters traveled after 33.2 seconds= 100.8 + 0.63= 101.43 
Is there an equation for this? Is this answer right?

Comment: $d=v_0t+\frac{1}{2} at^2$

Comment: what do the variables represent?

Comment: $v_0$ is the initial velocity, $t$ is time, and $a$ is the acceleration.

Comment: D= (5)(33.2) + 12(3.15)(33.2)^2

Comment: Did I put the variables in correctly? The little 12 confused me

Comment: Not sure what the downvote is for, OP clearly showed their own effort.

Comment: @JalaunRoss  D= (5)(33.2) + (1/2)(3.15)(33.2)^2     :)       The formula for d involves finding the area under the line $v(t) =v_0+ a t$.  If you graph that line, the distance travelled is equal to the area bounded by the $v(t)$ line, the $v$-axis, the $t$-axis, and the line $t=33.2$.  The area consists of a right isosceles triangle plus a rectangle.  The area of the triangle is $\frac12 a t^2$, and the area of the rectangle is $v_0 t$.

Comment: By the way, this site is not MathOverflow, which is for _professional_ mathematicians. This is the Mathematics Stack Exchange.